# Reference to a bean in a constructor of a different class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I am trying to migrate a legacy project into Spring Boot. There is an auto-generated class I've been struggling with. Please see below the original class that provides the interface for a web service.

```
/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI. JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "SomeWebService", targetNamespace = "http://www.somewebservice.com")
public class SomeWebService extends Service {

    private final static URL SomeWebService_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException SomeWebService_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName SomeWebService_QNAME = new QName("http://www.somewebservice.com", "SomeWebService");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(DataAccessLayer.systemProps.getProperty("configurable_service_url"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        SomeWebService_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        SomeWebService_EXCEPTION = e;
    }

    public SomeWebService() {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), SomeWebService_QNAME);
    }

    public SomeWebService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), SomeWebService_QNAME, features);
    }

    public SomeWebService(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SomeWebService_QNAME);
    }

    public SomeWebService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SomeWebService_QNAME, features);
    }

    public SomeWebService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public SomeWebService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return returns SomeWebService
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "SomeWebServicePort")
    public SomeWebService getSomeWebServicePort() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://www.somewebservice.com", "SomeWebServicePort"), SomeWebService.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *            A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy. Supported features not in
     *            the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return returns SomeWebService
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "SomeWebServicePort")
    public SomeWebService getSomeWebServicePort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://www.somewebservice.com", "SomeWebServicePort"), SomeWebService.class, features);
    }

    private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
        if (SomeWebService_EXCEPTION != null) {
            throw SomeWebService_EXCEPTION;
        }
        return SomeWebService_WSDL_LOCATION;
    }
}
```

Please note the line:

```
url = new URL(DataAccessLayer.systemProps.getProperty("configurable_service_url"));
```

This is how it is configured in the legacy code, in a static block...
The first thing I did is add a config class to pick up properties from a file as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:someWebservice.properties"})
public class SomeWebserviceConfiguration {
}
```

However, I am not able to figure out a way to create a bean (a url), and then use the bean in the constructors.
Can someone give me some ideas or point me in the right direction? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have found a solution. The code looks a bit unseemly. But it works.
First I need to add a config class, and make it ApplicationContextAware.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:somewebservice.properties" })
public class WebServiceConfiguration implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Value("${configurable_service_url}")
    private String serviceUrlProp;

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("serviceUrl")
    public URL getServiceUrl() throws MalformedURLException {
        return new URL(serviceUrlProp);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext) throws BeansException {
        ctx = appContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

This is where the property "configurable_service_url" gets picked up. We also create a URL bean and make it available in the container. The static ApplicationContext is for the web service class to grab and then it will get hold of the bean.

```
/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI. JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "SomeWebService", targetNamespace = "http://www.somewebservice.com")
public class SomeWebService extends Service {

    private final static QName SomeWebService_QNAME = new QName("http://www.somewebservice.com", "SomeWebService");


    public SomeWebService() {
        super((URL) BlazeConfiguration.getApplicationContext().getBean("getServiceUrl"), SomeWebService_QNAME);
    }

    public SomeWebService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super((URL) BlazeConfiguration.getApplicationContext().getBean("getServiceUrl"), SomeWebService_QNAME, features);
    }

    public SomeWebService(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SomeWebService_QNAME);
    }

    public SomeWebService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SomeWebService_QNAME, features);
    }

    public SomeWebService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public SomeWebService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return returns SomeWebService
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "SomeWebServicePort")
    public SomeWebService getSomeWebServicePort() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://www.somewebservice.com", "SomeWebServicePort"), SomeWebService.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *            A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy. Supported features not in
     *            the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return returns SomeWebService
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "SomeWebServicePort")
    public SomeWebService getSomeWebServicePort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://www.somewebservice.com", "SomeWebServicePort"), SomeWebService.class, features);
    }

}
```

In the constructor

```
public SomeWebService() {
    super((URL) BlazeConfiguration.getApplicationContext().getBean("getServiceUrl"), SomeWebService_QNAME);
}
```

I first tried to use the name "serviceUrl". But it complained that it could not find it in the application context. I had to print out all the available beans in the container to see that I needed to use "getServiceUrl", which is the method name, to retrieve the bean.